# Ceiling Fan with Light Causing AFCI Breaker to Trip - works in one room but not the other

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, smart-switch, afci

I have two rooms each with:

1. LED lights connected to a dimmer switch
2. Ceiling fan with integrated LED light connected to an on/off switch

My objective is to have the light in the ceiling fan to be controlled by the dimmer switch. The fan has a separate wire for the fan and one to control the integrated LED. All the switches, dimmers, and fans in both rooms are the same make and models.

In room 1, I used a 14/3 wire to the double-gang box with the switches and used the red wire to go from the LED light wire in the fan to the dimmer. All works well. This is in the first diagram in the image below.

In room 2, the dimmer switch and on/off switch are in separate boxes, due to how the studs are laid out (double-gang won't fit by door entry). So from the ceiling fan, I ran one 14/2 to the dimmer switch for the light control and one to the on/off switch for the fan control.

For room 2, all works well, but when I start sliding the dimmer for the lights up and down, it trips the breaker. When I disconnect the LED light control from the 14/2 wire in the fan, then I have no trips. I even removed the LED fixture feom the ceiling fan, and still trips. I replaced the ceiling fan with the same model again, and same thing happens.

Here's the layout and the specific components, any thoughts?

[image]

I haven't Tried Configuration 3 yet:

[image]

Here's where we are after trying all the configurations I could think of:

[image]

Components:

- Fan SC: Lutron Caseta Wireless Smart Fan Speed Control  (PD-FSQN-WH-R)
- Dimmer: Lutron Caseta Diva Smart Dimmer Switch (DVRF-6L-WH)
- Ceiling Fan: [Petersford 52 in. Integrated LED Indoor Brushed Nickel Ceiling Fan with Light Kit and Remote Control](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Petersford-52-in-Integrated-LED-Indoor-Brushed-Nickel-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote-Control-24425/301161479?mtc=SEM-BF-CDP-BNG-D27-027_020_CEILING_FANS-NA-MULTI-NA-DSA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-2023&cm_mmc=SEM-BF-CDP-BNG-D27-027_020_CEILING_FANS-NA-MULTI-NA-DSA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-2023-71700000115928130-58700008603407705-39700078642044814&gclid=85719d66f984141d01b1f8e1a81be9d9&gclsrc=3p.ds&msclkid=85719d66f984141d01b1f8e1a81be9d9).

Comment: I take it you have both the fan and light wires connected to 120VAC right now?

Comment: Yes. I installed a QO154M200PC just 4 months ago, and the QO115PAFGF and QO120PAFGF have been tripping with the 5 ceiling fans since then, so trying to handle that now.

Comment: I presume the existing power feed comes in at the switch box, no?

Comment: So the light dimmer has the main jump from the circuit. and then a jump from the the dimmer to the fa n on/off switch. That's pretty much about it for the power part. I did see a diagram where someone showed the power coming into the fan box and then the hot wire from there went into the neutrals on the wires for the switch. Not sure if that's legit, as it seems odd to me. Thoughts?

Comment: Tests: Arc is being sensed.
  Both rooms have same appliances.
  Probabilities: loose connection in light fixture, bad dimmer switch, loose connections, bad wire (stapled, etc)
  Try one at a time:
  1. swap fixtures. 
  2. swap dimmer switches. 
  3. Ensure tight connections and no neutral to grounding wire 
  4. remove one of the neutrals (both ends) for testing (you only need one to the light box). 
    IF still trips, try the other neutral. 
 If still trips, use the extra neutral to test each wire.
 If it is a wire, replace it if you can.

Comment: Tried a few things, with no luck: (1) Completely replaced wires, (2) Replaced Switches, (3) Replaced Fan, (4) Changed wiring configuration, (5) Replace ground wire in ceiling mount, (6) Remove Debri between ceiling mount and electrical box, (7) Tighten/Loosen ceiling mount, (8) Change Breaker, (9) Removed LEDs from Dimmer and only left fan light connected

Comment: @isaacco -- have you used the diagnostic steps for your breaker to figure out *why* it's tripping?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I even swapped out the breaker with the one from the bathroom. Breaker seems fine.

Comment: @isaacco no, we need the diagnostic trip info from the breaker to tell us how to fault-find on the *circuit*

Answer (score 1):

According to the [installation manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/28/28f7a9e9-247f-49a4-bb43-0fd0193f0818.pdf), this fan, as is very common, has:

- Black wire for fan power
- Blue wire for light power
- White neutral
- Green ground

With 14/3, everything is fine. But with 2 x 14/2 you are *splitting* the neutral. That violates the electrical code, because all currents must be equal/balanced in a cable. The electricity doesn't "know" whether to travel down the fan switch neutral or the light switch neutral.

With a GFCI you would almost always instantly get a breaker trip, because the odds of the current being balanced in each 14/2 cable at any given time is pretty much zero. AFCI *generally* is not as sensitive to this imbalance (as I understand it, some earlier generations of AFCI did function as a limited GFCI as well, but were not rated as a GFCI). My hunch is that because modern LED-compatible dimmer switches do some funny things to the power to make things work that *combined* with the splitting of the neutral you end up with a mess that the AFCI decides is not a good thing and trips.

While there *may* be some other solution that solves the AFCI problem, anything short of a 14/3 cable (or equivalent wires in conduit) will not solve the *electrical code* problem. So 2 x 14/2 is simply not an option here, and in fact the AFCI may have saved you from future troubles.

One solution, of course, is to use the remote kit. Some people love them, and I think the manufacturers *really* love them because at the cost of a few $ of hardware they allow anyone with an existing ceiling light (light only, no extra wire to run a fan) to install a combination light/fan. But the problem is that a remote *requires* use of the remote. If somebody made a permanently installable (so no batteries, compatible with other home automation, etc.) compatible single-gang remote-compatible fan/light switch, it would sell well. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if somebody has already done that - but I have no idea.

The other solution is to find a *single gang combination dimmer and fan control*, and that is easy enough to find. For example, the [Lutron from Amazon (and also available at Home Depot and other locations)](https://amzn.to/3RZXj2B):

[image: Lutron dimmer and fan control]

Replace one 14/2 cable and switch with 14/3 cable and this combination switch and you're all set. If you have no use for the other switch, either cover it with a blank plate or install an extra "convenience" receptacle.

Comment: I have that Maestro switch, but decided to keep everything on Caseta for the automation, especially with little kids leaving lights on everywhere. If you look at configuration 2 (the 3rd diagram) that uses two 14/3 wires. Even if I disconnect the LED lights and only use the dimmer for just the fan light, it trips. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: That's because the problem is **not** the "other" lights. The problem is splitting the neutral between fan (notor) and light (the one with the fan).

Comment: I added a diagram for configuration 3, with the junction box. Would that work?

Comment: The only way to keep everything balanced in every cable is (basically) if everything is in one box. I don't think it is legitimate to do this in 3 separate boxes.

Comment: @isaacco -- do both the dimmer and speed control require neutral, or can one get by without it?

Comment: The dimmer doesn't require a neutral. It doesn't even have a place for it on the dimmer. It just had ground, hot (line), load, and optional traveler for multi-way.

Comment: I uloaded a new comparison of configurations I have. I also tried replacing the dimmer with the Lutron MACL-153M, but same results. The Lutron Claro Smart On/Off Switch (DVRF-5NS) works and has a neutral wire. Can't use an on/off switch since the LED's hit 150W and become blinding.  Not sure if the problem is the noise by the dimming or the lack of a neutral wire in the dimmers. Still doesn't make sense why the similar configuration would work in 3 rooms, but 1.

Comment: Room 1 works because you used the right stuff - **14/3**. As far as why Room 2 works, I don't know. Does it have the exact same type of fan and light as Room 3 or possibly something a little different?

Comment: Exact same equipment. Even swapped them back and forth to see if that fixes this room, and no luck. All 4 rooms use 14/3 wires to the fan, as well. I even reran the wiring, I replaced the wiring just in case there was some breaks inside the romex sheath, I replaced the AFCI breaker, and pretty much everything I can think of. The only difference between this versus the others is the fan control has a 14/3 running from its box to the the box with the dimmer, line wire, and load wires. I tried so many variations of wiring, as well. I feel like I may be in the Twilight Zone.

Answer (score 1):

It was the dimmer make/model. I replaced the DVRF-6L with a PD-5NE which handles the electrical phase current differently.

The weird thing is the total loads are way below what's needed for the DVRF-6L (maybe 20% of the capacity).

This also solved it for a few other circuits in the past.

The other rooms with the DVRF-6L, which have the same exact loads, have tripped once or twice before. May have to replace those switches.

Overall, DVRF-6L should be taken off the market.

Additional notes: The new (DVRF-6L) uses 120V FORWARD PHASE w/ max 150w Dimmable LEDs, while the old one (PD-5NE) applies 120V FORWARD OR REVERSE PHASE w/ max 250w load. Oddly, reverse phase is newer and the older PD-5NE handles 100w more load. Check the prices, the PD-5NE still costs more, sometimes substantially more (over 20-50% from what I've observed). For AFCI breakers, its recommended to use reverse phase, the way they are designed to handle the current. Yet, in AFCI document note for the DVRF-6L, even the load center and breakers are mentioned for best results, and I checks all the boxes. Its a mess.

Comment: That's very curious that switching from a leading-edge to a trailing-edge dimmer fixed the problem

Comment: The new (DVRF-6L) uses 120V FORWARD PHASE w/ max 150w Dimmable LEDs, while the old one (PD-5NE) applies 120V FORWARD OR REVERSE PHASE w/ max 250w load. Oddly, reverse phase is newer and the older PD-5NE handles 100w more load. Check the prices, the PD-5NE still costs more, sometimes substantially more (over 20-50% from what I've observed). For AFCI breakers, its recommended to use reverse phase, the way they are designed to handle the current. Yet, in AFCI document note for the DVRF-6L, even the load center and breakers are mentioned for best results, and I checks all the boxes. Its a mess.